# Can we create a custom post template for a specific page template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I am working in wordpress for the first time and the client had a requirement that we create a template which will be used for multiple products as shown below

[image]

The question I do have is it possible to create a template in the wordpress admin section which would have multiple custom posts (e.g. Taking the example given above )for the following items

1. The hero image
2. The text in the hero image
3. The CTA
4. The infographic(s)
5. The alternating contents

Once these custom posts are set up, can all these posts be combined together to create one template in the backend which can be reused.

I apologize for the naiveness of the question but I come from a background where I have worked in CMS's before where you can create a template in the frontend and also create backend templates which map to the content in the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeap,

You can work with a page or single-cpt template with custom fields.
In both case, you can use a plugin like [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to set your fields.

I think [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) is a better choice in this case but if you are heading to custom-post-types, take a look at WordPress [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to understand how to create your custom single.php.

Answer (score 3):

Further to rafawhs answer, I think there is a little confusion as to what "custom post" indicates.  Most WP developers (in my opinion) would assume you are referring to a "custom post type" which is a special type of data in WP. Pages are a pre-defined custom post type, for example.  CPTs are mostly used to hold singular types of data, such as products, destinations on a travel site, authors on a book site, etc.

CPTs support taxonomy, custom fields and anything else you define as you create them, usually in your theme's functions.php file.

Based on what you described, rafawhs suggestion of Advanced Custom Fields (ACF plugin) is a valid one.  It allows you to manage these custom fields w/o digging too deeply into defining them yourself in PHP.  ACF provides a user-friendly UI for making selections while creating these custom fields.